# nodejs to get client IP Address inside setinterval function

Tags: javascript, node.js, intervals

I'm working with `nodejs` to get client IP Address. I configure the function inside `setinterval` function with below code:

```
var countdown2 = setInterval(function(){

async function baked(req, res, id){
    var getIP = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
    req.connection.remoteAddress || 
    req.socket.remoteAddress ||
    req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
    var IP = getIP.slice(7);
    
    console.log(IP);
}

baked();
}, 1000);
```

When I tried to run the code, it show me error like this:

```
(node:16432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

Any way how to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`request-ip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) package.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { mw } = require('request-ip');

app.use(mw());

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    setInterval(() => console.log(req.clientIp), 1000);
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log(`listening on 8000`))
```